# Set background to fill single screen on galaxy nexus

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-nexus, wallpaper

Currently galaxy nexus fits my image for all 5 of my screens, but I want my image to fill the whole screen, on every screen, so when u scroll between screens its the same background, and its the full image, not just parts of it. How can i Achieve this?

Comment: Which Android OS version is your Galaxy nexus currently running?  `Settings -> About phone -> Android version`

Comment: I found an app to do it for me, wallpaper wizardrii. Really good!

Comment: @Max Can you post that as a separate answer, instead of a comment? Then, don't forget to mark it as Answer two days later. :)